# Java Execute something in Process

Tags: java, process

I have the following code:

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
builder.inheritIO();
p = builder.start();
p.waitFor();
```

And in the created commandline, I would like to write e.g. "dir". How is this possible?

Best regards

**Edit:**
I have to run multiple commands and I can't use multiple cmds for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
Process p = builder.start();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream));
for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    writer.write("dir"); 
    writer.newLine(); 
    writer.flush();
}
// Now terminate
writer.write("exit"); 
writer.newLine(); 
writer.flush();
p.waitFor();
```

To read the output, use `p.getOutputStream()` (and `p.getErrorStream()` if you want to -- also consider the `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream()`).

Answer (score 1):

[`CMD.exe`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) on the Windows Command site says (in part),

> #### Options
>
> ```
> /C     Run Command and then terminate
> ```

So, you should be able to use

```
cmd /C dir
```

But it's probably a better idea to prefer a pure Java solution using [`File.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29).

Comment: But I have to run multiple commands and I can't use multiple cmds for that.

Comment: Create a batch, shell or cmd file and execute that.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/88888889-java-util/426-from-runtimeexec-to-processbuilder.html

```
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process process = runtime.exec(command);
```

Comment: But I have to run multiple commands and I can't use multiple cmds for that.